# requirements about or requirements for

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs

i try to build a phrase in the context of Master application : 
 We said :

> - let me know if there are further requirements for my application .

or

> - let me know if there are  further requirements about my application .

Comment: If you Google that, you'll certainly find your answer.  Try that.

Comment: i find this : https://www.google.com/search?q=If+you+Google+that%2C+you%27ll+certainly+find+your+answer.+Try+that.&oq=If+you+Google+that%2C+you%27ll+certainly+find+your+answer.+Try+that.&aqs=chrome..69i57.189j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I meant Google Books.  Try it.  https://www.google.com.br/#q=requirements+for&tbm=bks  and https://www.google.com.br/#tbm=bks&q=requirements+about You'll see that "requirements for" produces many more results than "requirements about", which is not wrong and is used in more specific contexts.

Comment: I find this: _Nutrient Requirements for Foxes and Minks_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are requirements as to what your application must be or must accomplish, I would definitely use "for".

If the "requirements" you think they might memtion are more tangential to the app itself, such as hardware environment, I would use something more specific than "about"; like "related to", "that might affect", etc. ,

Or else, don't call them "requirements" but rather "data inputs" or "runtime environment" or (whatever specific type of related factors you think they might mention that affect your app but are not part of it)